# Best method to remove items from a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ienumerable

I have a list of 500.000 to 1.000.000 instances of `MyClass`, which has these properties:

```
class MyClass
{
    string ParentId;
    string Name;
    DateTime StartDate;
    DateTime EndDate;
}
```

The data could look like this:

```
ParentId | Name    | StartDate    | EndDate
----------------------------------------------
parent1  | alpha   | 01-01-2011   | 02-02-2015
parent1  | beta    | 01-01-2011   | 02-02-2014
parent2  | gamma   | 01-01-2012   | 02-02-2011
```

I need to filter the list so it contains the "alpha" and "gamma" objects. The "beta" object should be excluded because it has the same parent as alpha, but an earlier EndDate.

I.e. the resulting list should only contain one instance per ParentId (the one with the latest EndDate).

The filtering needs to perform well.

Comment: `myClasses.Where(x => x.Name == "alfa" || x.Name == "gamma").Distinct()`, it should be performant - use the `System.Timer()` if you want to understand how quick

Comment: Filter and remove aren't the same. What are you asking? And what do you mean "perform well"? How many objects are stored? How deep is the tree? For a large number and/or deep trees you'll need a tree structure

Comment: @M4N between 500.000 -1000.000

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing this in a database?

Comment: Why so many? Were they loaded from a DB? Why not filter them in the DB? Anyway, with so many items you need a specialized tree collection, not a simple list, especially if there are many or deep parent-child relations.

Comment: @callum similar to first answer, however both miss check with EndDate comparison. If i understand expected result, filtering is NOT on name == 'alpha' or 'gamma', but where group on ParentID && where max EndDate --> which based on example results in alpha and gamma records.

Comment: It should have been done on db, but it was not an option :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501.aspx) and `Select`:

```
var filtered = list
              .GroupBy(mc=>mc.ParentId)
              .Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(mc=>mc.EndDate).First())
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do `.SelectMany().Distinct()` to achieve the same results?

Comment: @CallumLinington - I really don't see a reason to use `SelectMany` here, `First` is more elegant because we *know* we only need one element from each group. If we know select just one element, we don't need `Distinct` either.

Comment: What if the groups don't have any in?

Comment: @Callum Linington - I'm not sure what you mean. The groups are created from existing instances of `MyClass` (poor name). An empty group cannot exist here - it would not have been generated in the first place. We take `MyClass`, and make a group based on its `ParentId`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to filter out beta for the reasons explained and not for its bare name. Here's what you can use to achieve such result:

```
myClasses.GroupBy(i => i.ParentId)
    .Select(i => i.OrderByDescending(i2 => i2.EndDate).First());
```

Comment: Note that you are using `i` twice in nested lambdas: `i => i.OrderByDescending(i => i.EndDate)` - this doesn't compile. Other than that, this is identical to my answer.

Comment: I edited and fixed it: thanks. As for your answer, i voted it :)

Answer (score 2):

While the currently accepted answer (by @Kobi) is correct and is probably the simplest solution, it might not be the "best" solution.

Especially, since you mentioned that you might have quite a lot of items in the list and that the solution should perform well, I thought I'd check how a solution without LINQ performs.

This is my solution:

```
var tempDict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
foreach (var data in list) // list is the List<MyClass>
{
    MyClass existing;
    if (!tempDict.TryGetValue(data.ParentId, out existing))
    {
        // Put item into temp dictionary (use ParentId as key)
        tempDict[data.ParentId] = data;
    }
    else
    {
        // Check if the instance in the temp dictionary has an
        // earlier EndDate. If yes, replace it.
        if (existing.EndDate < data.EndDate) // replace
            tempDict[data.ParentId] = data;
    }
}

var result = tempDict.Values.ToList();
```

A quick comparison (using 500.000 items) showed that this solution is about 3 to 4 times faster than the LINQ-version (depending on the number of unique ParentId values).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily filter a `List<T>` using `Linq.Where`

```
var result = myList
    .Where(item => item.Name == "gamma" || item.Name == "alfa")
    .ToList();
```

If you want to distinct the output on a certain feild, you can either use [MoreLinq's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) DistinctBy

Or `GroupBy`:

```
var result = myList
    .Where(item => item.Name == "gamma" || item.Name == "alfa")
    .GroupBy(item => item.ParentId)
    .Select(g => g.First()) //Selection logic
    .ToList();
```

Comment: needs `Distinct()` as well? to make sure its unique

Comment: sorry my question is unclear. I cannot filter on the name, I need to look at the ParentId and the EndDate

Comment: I tried to answer taking that into consideration. Let me know if it's correct.

Comment: The OP wasn't very clear with the requirements. The Group, Select, Orderby in the other answers is the solution here, because I think they want the newest item per parent. "gamma" etc are red herrings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it, this method work fine and fast  with large array:

```
var groupesList = yourList.GroupBy(x => x.ParentId,
     (y, set) => new {Key = y, Value = set.First(s => s.EndDate == set.Max(r => r.EndDate))}).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```